# Border of table does not fit together

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

In my latex file I want to create a table. My current code looks like the following:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\bf \ul Type of query}}                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{\bf \ul Fees in EUR}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Current Deed (full query a register number)}                                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.36}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Current portion of extract (query of the A-, B- or C-sheet insert a number)}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.79}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query the last diary number (seal)}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.68}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query the collection of documents (each document polled)}                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.05}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Interrogation of persons directory (per person polled)}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.68}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query the historical register number (list of deleted entries) for the last five years} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.68}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query the historical register number (list of deleted entries) without any time limit}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.99}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Deed on a specific date (depending polled insert number)}                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.99}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Land Registry-part excerpt on a specific date (depending interrogated sheet)}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{2.31}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query the last diary number (seal) on a specific date}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{2}                    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query the information about a journal number (additional information)}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.68}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Search for purchase contracts per cadastral}                                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.68}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Information on a property group in the group directory}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.68}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to 500 m)}                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.36}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to 1,000 m)}                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{11.60}                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to 2,000 m)}                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{44}                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Excerpt from the land register without land address (for up to ten plots)}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.36}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Excerpt from the land register without land address (for 11-100 Land)}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{11.60}                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Excerpt from the land register with Land address (for up to ten plots)}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.57}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Excerpt from the land register with Land address (for 11 up to 100 plots)}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{13.70}                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (for up to 10 hits)}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1.05}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (up to 100 hits)}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{3.36}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (for up to 1,000 hits)}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{34}                   \\ \hline
Querying public corporations                                                                                 & 1.58                                      \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Caption for LOF]{Fee overview to access land registry.\protect\footnotemark}
\label{table:feesOfLandRegistry}   
\end{table}
```

However, when compiling the code I get:
[image]

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I changed the table to:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\bf \ul Type of query}}                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{\bf \ul Fees in EUR}} \\ \hline
Current Deed (full query a register number)                                             & 3.36                 \\ \hline
Current portion of extract (query of the A-, B- or C-sheet insert a number)            & 1.79                \\ \hline
Query the last diary number (seal)                                                    & 1.68                 \\ \hline
Query the collection of documents (each document polled)                               & 1.05                 \\ \hline
Interrogation of persons directory (per person polled)                                 & 1.68                 \\ \hline
Query the historical register number (list of deleted entries) for the last five years & 1.68                 \\ \hline
Query the historical register number (list of deleted entries) without any time limit  & 3.99                 \\ \hline
Deed on a specific date (depending polled insert number)                               & 3.99                 \\ \hline
Land Registry-part excerpt on a specific date (depending interrogated sheet)           & 2.31                 \\ \hline
Query the last diary number (seal) on a specific date                                  & 2                    \\ \hline
Query the information about a journal number (additional information)                  & 1.68                 \\ \hline
Search for purchase contracts per cadastral                                            & 1.68                 \\ \hline
Information on a property group in the group directory                                 & 1.68                 \\ \hline
Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to 500 m)                          & 3.36                 \\ \hline
Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to 1,000 m)                        & 11.60                \\ \hline
Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to 2,000 m)                        & 44                   \\ \hline
Excerpt from the land register without land address (for up to ten plots)              & 3.36                 \\ \hline
Excerpt from the land register without land address (for 11-100 Land)                  & 11.60                \\ \hline
Excerpt from the land register with Land address (for up to ten plots)                 & 3.57                 \\ \hline
Excerpt from the land register with Land address (for 11 up to 100 plots)              & 13.70                \\ \hline
Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (for up to 10 hits)        & 1.05                 \\ \hline
Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (up to 100 hits)           & 3.36                 \\ \hline
Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (for up to 1,000 hits)     & 34                   \\ \hline
Querying public corporations                                                                                 & 1.58                                      \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Caption for LOF]{Fee overview to access land registry.\protect\footnotemark}
\label{table:feesOfLandRegistry}
\end{table}
```

BUT I still get the error.

Comment: Why all the `\multicolumn` commands? With the exception of those in the header row, I don't think any of them do anything useful.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Please see my update!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. removing all `multicolumn` worked for me ;)

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Is it the white space to the right or the missing vertical lines on the header line?

Answer (score 5):

- Your table is much too wide because of the first column and the contents sticks into the right margin without the horizontal lines following.
- It does not make sense to me, using `X` for the numbers, but `l` for the long texts. The example below uses `X` for the text column.
- `\bf` is deprecated since many decades. LaTeX2e has `\bfseries` or `\textbf{...}`.
- `\ul` underlining command of package `soul`? There are already much too many lines. Also `\ul` expects an argument in curly braces.
- The example uses package `booktabs` for three nice lines. More are not necessary.
- Longer texts in the left column which use more than a line are formatted with indentation of the second and later lines.
- The example makes some font setups to get a proper € sign.
- Package `siunitx` is used to format the euro amounts at the decimal point.
- Also the package provides `\SI` for typesetting numbers with units with proper spacing and the prevention of line breaks between number and unit.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\sisetup{
  input-decimal-markers={.},
  input-ignore={,},
  group-minimum-digits=4,
  group-separator={,},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  >{\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 }X
  S[table-format=2.2]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Type of query}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fees in \texteuro}} \\
\midrule
Current Deed (full query a register number)
& 3.36                 \\
Current portion of extract (query of the A-, B- or C-sheet insert a number)
& 1.79                \\
Query the last diary number (seal)
& 1.68                 \\
Query the collection of documents (each document polled)
& 1.05                 \\
Interrogation of persons directory (per person polled)
& 1.68                 \\
Query the historical register number (list of deleted entries) for the last
five years & 1.68                 \\
Query the historical register number (list of deleted entries) without any
time limit  & 3.99                 \\
Deed on a specific date (depending polled insert number)
& 3.99                 \\
Land Registry-part excerpt on a specific date (depending interrogated sheet)
& 2.31                 \\
Query the last diary number (seal) on a specific date
& 2                    \\
Query the information about a journal number (additional information)
& 1.68                 \\
Search for purchase contracts per cadastral
& 1.68                 \\
Information on a property group in the group directory
& 1.68                 \\
Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to \SI{500}{\meter})
& 3.36                 \\
Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to \SI{1,000}{\meter})
& 11.60                \\
Query from the digital cadastral (DKM graphics) (up to \SI{2,000}{\meter})
& 44                   \\
Excerpt from the land register without land address (for up to ten plots)
& 3.36                 \\
Excerpt from the land register without land address (for 11--100 Land)
& 11.60                \\
Excerpt from the land register with Land address (for up to ten plots)
& 3.57                 \\
Excerpt from the land register with Land address (for 11 up to 100 plots)
& 13.70                \\
Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (for up to 10
hits)        & 1.05                 \\
Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (up to 100 hits)
& 3.36                 \\
Search plot addresses in Address Directory - address search (for up to 1,000
hits)     & 34                   \\
Querying public corporations
& 1.58                                      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Caption for LOF]{Fee overview to access land
registry.\protect\footnotemark}
\label{table:feesOfLandRegistry}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Since the width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\linewidth`, the `\centering` instruction between `\begin{table}[htbp]` and `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{...}` is redundant.

Comment: @Mico It could be added to the definition of `table`, if all tables should be centered. `\centering` sets `\parindent` to zero (inside the `table` it is zero already, but who knows, what a class or package might set). Also it is seen by `\caption`. It's default is centering, but again, who knows, what package and classes might do. And if the table is made smaller at a later time, then adding `\centering` is likely to be forgotten.

Comment: Many thanks for these explanations for why the `\centering` instruction needn't be redundant. :-)  A separate matter: By default, `siunitx` interprets the `,` (comma) symbol in `\SI{1,000}{\meter}` and `\SI{2,000}{\meter}` as a decimal marker and replaces it with `.` in the output; as a result, the lengths look like they're 1 and 2 meters instead of 1,000 and 2,000 meters, respectively. I suppose this issue could be circumvented by issuing the instruction `\sisetup{ input-ignore = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4, group-separator = {,} }` in the preamble.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I had overlooked it. Also I had to remove the comma from option `input-decimal-markers`.