# Wide table issue

Tags: tables

how can I put reduce the width of this table?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}
      \usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.2in, right=1in]{geometry}
       \pagestyle{plain}
        \usepackage[english]{babel}
         \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
          \usepackage{tabularx}
          \begin{document}
            \begin{table} [h]
            \centering
          \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Materials} & \textbf{N. plies} &\textbf{Plies orientation} 
                &\textbf{Conductivity W/mK} \\
                    \midrule
                Glass fiber+carbon fiber/epoxy resin & 9 & Isotropic glass fiber + 
                  unidirectional carbon fiber & Resulted from experimental campaign  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
                    \caption{Hybrid plate's characteristics.}
       \end{table}
       \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you load the `tabularx` package, you might as well make use of its machinery and allow line breaks in 3 of the 4 columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in, left=1.2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\si' macro

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[h]     
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LcLL @{}}
      \toprule
      Materials & No.\ plies & Plies orientation & 
      Conductivity (\si[per-mode=symbol]{\watt\per\milli\kelvin}) \\
      \midrule
      Glass fiber + carbon fiber\slash epoxy resin & 
      9 & 
      Isotropic glass fiber + unidirectional carbon fiber & 
      Resulted from experimental campaign  \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
   \caption{Hybrid plate's characteristics.}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A variation on Mico's good answer: hanging paragraphs in the multiline cells will help in distinguishing the table rows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\sisetup{
  per-mode=symbol,
  bracket-unit-denominator=false,
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\leftskip=1em\parindent=-1em}X}
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YcYY}
\toprule
Materials &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Plies} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\splitcell{Conductivity \\ (\unit{\watt\per\meter\per\kelvin})}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
& No. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Orientation} \\
\midrule
Glass fiber+carbon fiber/epoxy resin &
  9 &
  Isotropic glass fiber + unidirectional carbon fiber &
  Resulted from experimental campaign  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Hybrid plate's characteristics.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I locally define a column type to ease inputting the table specification and also a local command for the multiline header.

With `\leftskip=1em` all lines are indented, but with `\parindent=-1em` the first line will start 1em to the left, so we get hanging indentation.

[image]

Comment: +1 as well. :-) A trick I learned several years ago from Heiko O. (possibly from [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248118/5001), but not entirely sure): `\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em` may be more straightforward to decipher (maybe because it's more semantic?) than `\leftskip=1em\parindent=-1em`.